# Display localStorage value in html header

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-mobile, append, local-storage

I Want to Give a welcome message to the user and use his name from the localStorage that have been updated after he filled a form.

As an example = "Hello John!" inside  
For the code i thought to use -
"Hello" + variableName + "!"

I tried several ways but with no success.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="displayname">
        <h1 >
          <!--Here I Want the Welcome Message-->
        </h1>
        </div>
```

the name stored in localStorage.name and i need the value to be displayed

Will be glad to hear some suggestions,Thanks.

this is the localstorage script:

```
function saveSettings() {
localStorage.name = $('#your_name').val();
localStorage.id = $('#id_number').val();
localStorage.email = $('#email_address').val();
localStorage.bdate = $('#birth_date').val();
localStorage.mphone = $('#mobile_phone').val();
localStorage.hphone = $('#home_phone').val();
localStorage.lnumber = $('#license_number').val();
}
```

Comment: The thing is displaying locastorage items is easy. What you need is a mprehensive guide on how to store and retrieve localstorage items -- here is basic guide -- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp --- and here a more comprehenive guide -- http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/

Comment: Ive tried this way with no success either,there's a chance you show me the code that you would be using?

Comment: So when when you do (var name = localStorage.getItem("name");) nothing comes back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised i prepared a Demo for you. I put many Remarks in the code to make it easier to understand. Its not using Json but its using an Async funtion to Loop around Local Storage. It works very well. Most of all its very reliable, and never breaks Local storage.

You Can Add and delete Users but is open to all sorts of Possibilities, as you will Read from the Remarks. It can Act as a Basic database for Storing data in LocalStore.

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/3vynv918/

Jquery

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    // an async function to loop around with ease
    var asyncFor = function(params) {

        var defaults = {
          total: 0,
          limit: 1,
          pause: 10,
          context: this
        },
          options = $.extend(defaults, params),
          def = $.Deferred(),
          step = 0,
          done = 0;

        this.loop = function() {
          if (done < options.total) {
            step = 0;
            for (; step < options.limit; step += 1, done += 1) {
              def.notifyWith(options.context, [done]);
            }
            setTimeout.apply(this, [this.loop, options.pause]);
          } else {
            def.resolveWith(options.context);
          }
        };

        setTimeout.apply(this, [this.loop, options.pause]);
        return def;
      };



    $(document).on( "click", "#sub", function() {
    var name = $('#user').val();

     var id ="";

     //create a random id for the user so we can distinguish him in local storage incase of Possible duplicate first names

     var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ )

    id += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    //store the data from the form to localstorage. we use user as the kind of dataset so it will enable to store as many datasets as possible. eg stock, places, locations. So you can group data. In this example we are storing Users

    localStorage.setItem(id, 'user['+name+'#name]' ); // you can add many form items by seperating them by # eg name#surname#address. I put #name as an example, but in this demo we dont read that. So we call that spare data as it does nothing, although it gets stored for each user.

    $('#usersname').html(name);

    show_localstore()

    });

    // get all items from local storage and show them
    function show_localstore() {
    var mylistitems = "";
    $('#storage').empty();

    asyncFor({
      total: localStorage.length,
      context: this
    }).progress(function(step) {

    var propertyName = localStorage.key(step);
    var keyv = propertyName;
    var value = localStorage.getItem(propertyName);

 //check the dataset if its user. If you have other datasets then change user to that dataset  
    if (value.indexOf('user') > -1) {

    var matches = value.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);

    if (matches) {

    var words = matches[1];

    var match = words.split('#');

    var username = match[0];  // matches the first item, if you have many then set up variables and change the match value eg surname = match[1] address = match[2] etc

    $("#storage").append('<p><a>user_id='+keyv+'<a>--username='+username+'</a></p>');   

    }}

    }).done(function() {

    });

    };

    //delete localstore item by selecting the User_id value. 
    $(document).on( "click", "#delsub", function() {  
    var id  = $('#deluser').val();
    localStorage.removeItem(id);
     show_localstore()   
    });

     show_localstore()     
    });
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much.
But unfortunately you didn't understand my question,
im already using ajax/json database.
I just want to write the localstore.name value into a div inside the dom.

Comment: Its ok, no worries. Do you actually have localstorage set up? if you can you post the code you have so far and update the question i can help. also if you use chrome, open developer tools and type in the console. localstorage --- do you see any data?

Comment: yeah i see this - bdate: "1994-03-14"email: "ofiro.ohayon@gmail.com"hphone: "089750585"id: "312545197"length: 7lnumber: "574-444-333"mphone: "0504229998"name: "ofiro.ohayon@yahoo.com"